# `overflow-scroll: false` not working with `$ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);`

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework

How can I use JS scroll on an  if I set $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false); globally?

Below code doesn't work:

```
<ion-content 
  overflow-scroll="false">
  <div class="list">
  <ul>
   // <li>s
  </ul>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

I'm experiencing issues with my fixed `<ion-content>` which has scrollable content in iOS safari. When I tried with `$ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);` all looks okay, but I don't want JS scrolling in other `ion-content`s considering the performance.

I'm using **"ionic": "1.1.0".**

Comment: what you want to do? are you asking for stop scrolling on single page? or you want to stop scrolling for entire app?

Comment: for single page use `scroll="false"` instead of `overflow-scroll=false`

If you wish to have a full screen content area, just don't use <ion-content> and keep it in a <ion-pane>. Thanks!

Comment: No. I wanted JS scroll on that ion content even though I set jsScrolling to false globally. Turns out, it's not possible in 1.1.

Comment: then update your ionic to 1.+ last version

Comment: Yes, I'm going to. :) Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Naitik! Appreciated your help.